# Match list with two values in Scala

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming, match

I want to write an algorithm that matches a list with two values in Scala.

For example, if I have the following list:

```
val list = List(1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 14, 18)
```

And have this two values:

```
val a = 4

val b = 14
```

I want to get this list:

```
val result = List(6, 8, 9, 14)
```

If was thinking about using the `intersect` method of Scala, but that only works with two lists.

I also thought about using a for cycle, but that is not functional.

So I ended up with no idea on how to solve this problem.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: why not filter list? `list.filter(x => x >= 4 && x <= 14)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh, but you **can** use `intersect`, like so:

```
scala> List(1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 14, 18) intersect (4 to 14)
res1: List[Int] = List(6, 8, 9, 14)
```

And you can reverse the order, but the resulting collection type is different.

```
scala> 4 to 14 intersect List(1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 14, 18)
res2: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(6, 8, 9, 14)
```

Takeaway: Scala has lots of different collection types, but many of them do play well together.

Comment: With the second example: if the result must be a `List`, you can just call `toList` on the resulting `Vector`.

Comment: Your answer really helped me. But let's say that I have a value in Calendar format. For example if it is a time like "2:30". For what I see I can't use "to" because it only works with integer values. Is there a functonal workaround for this?

Comment: @JoãoAlves, glad I could help.  You are correct that a `Range` collection can't be used for date/time values.  That's a different question and the answer will depend on the input data type. (string? java.util.Calendar?)  Be clear about what you are trying to achieve and what you've tried so far. [BTW, the most helpful answer to your questions should be marked as the accepted answer.]

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a list with the following syntax:

```
val list = List(1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 14, 18)
```

It will create `scala.collection.immutable.List` for you. And if I understood you task correctly, this oneliner can solve your problem:

```
list filter { element => a to b contains element }
```

so if a == 4, and b == 14 you will get:

```
res0: List[Int] = List(6, 8, 9, 14)
```

Answer (score 1):

With recursion, pattern matching, and guards. The interesting part is the guard `if(h >= a && h <= b)` where the head of the list is checked if it is within `a` and `b`. If so, it is pre-pended to the result list.

```
def slice(a: Int, b: Int, xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = xs match {
  case Nil                         => Nil
  case h::t if(h >= a && h <= b)   => h :: slice(a,b,t)
  case h::t                        => slice(a,b,t)
}
```

Tests:

```
scala> slice(4,14, list)
res25: List[Int] = List(6, 8, 9, 14)

scala> slice(18,20, list)
res26: List[Int] = List(18)

scala> slice(1,3, list)
res27: List[Int] = List(1, 3)

scala> slice(-2,0, list)
res28: List[Int] = List()

...
```

Tail recursive implementation left as an exercise. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using a for comprehension,

```
for ( i <- xs if i >= 4 && i <= 14) yield i
```

For ease of use consider this implicit class,

```
implicit class OpsList(xs: List[Int]) {
  def segment(a: Int, b:Int) = for ( i <- xs if i >= a && i <= b) yield i 
}
```

and so

```
xs.segment(4,14)
List(6, 8, 9, 14)
```

Answer (score 0):

Knight71's comment is the most concise, general, and efficient answer, as it will work with more than just `Ints` and doesn't potentially require searching through an entire second list for each element of the first list:

```
val result = list filter (x => x >= 4 && x <= 14)
```

You may want to create a function to make your intent even more clear:

```
def between(a: Int, b: Int)(x: Int): Boolean = x >= a && x <= b

val result = list filter between(4, 14)
```

This version is really nice if you are chaining a lot of different criteria together to come up with a final result.  It separates the list of applied criteria from their implementation details.